# Clear all controls with a For Next Loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a button to reset a tic tac toe game but it is not working. Every example I find shows the same layout. Any ideas what is wrong?

The initial buttons are disabled until you start a new game (this button). It should be enabling the buttons and clearing all the X's and O's...

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is Button Then
       ctl.Text = ""
       ctl.Enabled = True
    End If
Next ctl
```

When clicked, nothing happens...

EDIT: Upon further investigation I see that it is only affecting the "New Game" button. The actual buttons I want affected are within a GroupBox is that the reason? How can I run through the controls within a GroupBox?

Comment: Are these Buttons child of `Me` or did you place them inside another Container? BTW, `For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button) ... Next` (or  `As Button`)

Comment: Just updated post, you were spot on in your thinking.

Comment: Then loop the `Controls` collection of this other Container.

Comment: Ahh GroupBox1.Controls... Doh! I spent an hour on this...

Comment: BTW2, you should add (and dock) your Buttons to a TableLayoutPanel with proportional Columns/Rows, to automatically organize and scale these elements. The TableLayoutPanel should be placed inside another Container (e.g., a standard Panel)

Comment: *"The TableLayoutPanel should be placed inside another Container"*. Why? A `TableLayoutPanel` IS a `Panel`. It works like any other container so there's no need for another container just to contain it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Separation of Layout Concerns. Branch of the more widely known *Separation of Concerns*. -- In all major applications (I mean *all of them*), layout elements are separated in (often nested) Containers. It becomes clearly necessary when you have to handle scaling caused by DpiAwareness: UI elements may scale using different *logic* (Font, Graphics, Controls' internals  etc.) and need to be separated, to avoid mixing different scaling factors and logic. Otherwise, you'll have to fight against your own design all the time. Use Spy++ or Inspect to verify what I'm saying.

Comment: That makes no sense. Like I said, a `TableLayoutPanel` IS a `Panel`. Why would you need to put a `Panel` inside another `Panel` if there's nothing else in between? There's nothing wrong with nesting containers if there are other controls involved, e.g. if the `Panel` was going to contain the `TableLayoutPanel` and other controls, but there's no indication that that is the case here. There's already a `GroupBox` and then the `TableLayoutPanel` inside that to contain and layout the `Buttons`? What purpose would a `Panel` serve that one of those two containers doesn't already?

Comment: @jmcilhinney You didn't use Spy++ or Inspect to check the Layout of some commercial program (or apps that ship with the System). E.g., each Parent can have different settings and child Controls inherits those settings Other Controls, for their specificity, may need different care. A GroupBox is not a `ScrollableControl` and sets the `ContainerControl` style, a Panel implements `IArrangedElement` and so on. All these details are considered when a Layout is designed, combined with how visual inheritance works in this platform. You, personally, don't? Well, I suppose one can live without it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access those controls with `GroupBox1.Controls` (or whatever the groupbox is named.) Just use `GroupBox1.Controls` instead of `Me.Controls`.